# While working with Oracle ADF how can I manage to detect the pressed key over a specific input text

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf

Looking for a simple and clear way to detect when a enter key was pressed over an input text in order to be able to perform the move to the next input field and get triggered the validation related events.
After several attempts I found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to add a couple of tags within the input text source code tags, one for the Javascript which will be triggered by onkeypress and another one for the clientlistener which will "attach" the defined Javascript function to the specific input text.
Tested on Jdeveloper 11.1.2.1.0, this will cause a tab-like behaviour if the enter key is pressed, useful to manage an input from a barcodescanner which cannot be programmed to send a tab keychar after the reading

```
<af:inputText> .... [here you will have several tags and attributes, just start to write before the closing tag for your inputText]

                                <af:resource type="javascript">
                                function takeEnterAsTab(componentEvent)
                                {
                                    var evt = componentEvent.getNativeEvent();

                                    if (AdfAgent.AGENT.getKeyCode(evt) == 13) 
                                    {
                                        AdfFocusUtils.focusNextTabStop(componentEvent.getNativeEventTarget());
                                    }
                                }
                                </af:resource>
                                <af:clientListener method="takeEnterAsTab" type="keyPress"/>       

</af:inputText>
```